# Compiled Perl GUI Application

Tags: perl, qt, user-interface, gtk, tk-toolkit

I'm searching for options to make a GUI based application.

Application needs to intact with http servers, database and GUI.
so best option that I know is to have perl.

I'm searching for a way to Compile the code to ensure the security 
also easy development of GUI.

I have started the same with Perl/TK but writing each and every lines of GUI is taking lot of time also its really hard to debug.

Is there any option to that the GUI building can be like QT or .NEt so that the GUI controls can be easily dragged and drop.

If I'm using PerlQT, is drag and drop possible?
Is it possible to compile the code in PerlQT?
Whether this will work in both linux and windows?
Is there any other option like PerlGTK or something else?

Answer (score 1):

If you think “compiling” a Perl script will solve any problems, you are likely to face a disappointment.

- Usually, the perl interpreter is just bundled with the plain source code and any used modules into one gargantuan executable. The script isn't really compiled. This makes nothing easier. Also, compilation has *nothing* to do with security, and can provide a bit of obscurity at best.
- Otherwise, you could tread the crazy route and use something that serializes the Perl opcodes into C code, and compile that. Do note that while perl compiles the source into opcodes, it already executes parts of it, so that running the opcode serialization is not the same as running the actual program.

On *nix systems, compiling a Perl script is silly, as the interpreter is readily available.

If you want to fuse Perl and foreign code into one program (!= one executable), take a look at the XS language (binds C to Perl), or at the `Inline` family of modules.

(Perl-)Qt is pretty awesome, but the last time I looked at the recent bindings, that stuff looked undermaintained and experimental. I am sure that you could leverage the QtDesigner somehow for the designing part, and hook up Perl code with that. This should be pretty portable if you have a compiler on every target system. har har.

Other GUI Toolkits you should seriously consider are GTK and Wx. .Net is right out.

Please realize that Perl is a very dynamic language. While compilation isn't likely to be useful, you can use functional programming techniques like anonymous subroutines and metaprogramming techniques like compile time code generation to simplify your GUI coding. If you write Perl like you would write Java, or other fairly static (& compiled) languages, I wouldn't be suprised if Perl seems painful.

Comment: The one reason for compiling things into one lump is so that an application can be relatively easily redistributed without weird versioning problems. That is, for packaging and not for security. (Yes, this does make applying patches more awkward; it's a trade-off.)